# Does $LL(K)$ grammar has one to one correspondence with $DCFL$?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, ll-k

- Does $LL(K)$ grammar has one to one correspondence with $DCFL$ ?

---

If I am understanding right, then the given statement says that $2$ distinct $LL(k)$ have one to one mapping, i.e they should not generate the same $DCFL$.

Let us say:-

$G1 : S-> aB,B->a$ generates $aa$ and $G2: S->aa$ also generates $aa$.

Here, both the grammars are $LL(1)$, and generate the same language $aa$ implying many to one mapping and not one to one .

Moreover, If we take a $DCFL$, $$a^n\bigcup a^nb^n$$, it has no $LL(k)$ grammar for it and another $DCFL$, say $$a^m b^{m+n}$$, then it also has no $LL(K)$ grammar for it.

---

- Similarly, I think the statement that "Does $LR(K)$ grammar has one to one correspondence with DCFL" is also false.

---

---

Am I right in the reasoning of both the above statements ?

If both are false, then what should be the correct interpretation of the above statements ?

Comment: The structure and haphazard formatting of your post makes it hard to follow. I'm closing as duplicate because we have a post that answers the bulleted questions. We don't do proofreading, so: do you have a specific questionabout your proof sketch? *Of course* giving a language in DCFL \ LL(k) shows that the sets are not equal; what's missing is a proof that the proposed language *is* in this difference of sets.

Comment: My mistake: the linked question only answers this one together with the rather [well-known fact](http://planetmath.org/lrk#Thmthm1) that  DCFL = LR(1) = LR(k).